# google chrome consider your site as malware

Tags: security, joomla, google-chrome, malware

I just discovered that one of my site was considered by Chrome as a malware.

Here's what is Google Chrome is showing:

> The website at ___ contains elements from the site ___, which appears to host malware – software that can hurt your computer or otherwise operate without your consent. Just visiting a site that contains malware can infect your computer.

My site uses Joomla 1.5 as a CMS and had securities issue, one of the template ("beez" I think was the name of the template) that comes with Joomla contained a virus, Now I updated the Joomla and removed the template, and I thought that fixed the problem.

Now Chrome is still considering my site as a malware. Any Ideas how I would fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think this fits in the trilogy anywhere; it's really SEO and webmaster specific.

Comment: It will take a while (possibly days) before the changes you made take effect, it's not going to be instant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google is using the database of this organization for malware reports.

http://www.stopbadware.org/home/reportsearch

Check if you're in there - if you are, go to google webmaster tools and there you should be able to request a revalidation.

http://www.stopbadware.org/home/reviewinfo

Answer (score 1):

You might still have a problem with content that contains malware. When a wordpress site of mine got hacked, there was a stray piece of malware in the static html. You need to check every file that displays :(

Good luck.